# Laravel returns internal error 500 for request

Tags: laravel

There's a trouble with Laravel/Vue single-page application.
I've to request JSON from client form to Laravel route via REST Api (POST method), and that data will be sent to email.
In a local server under artisan the request and all other features of the project works perfectly, but when i deployed it at the host, there is an internal error 500, and the request doesn't work.
Sorry for the large code, but i don't know how to solve the problem severel days, it's some kind of Laravel-armageddon:

```
    {
        "message": "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"narzantaria@gmail.com\" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"534\", with message \"534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbup\r\n534-5.7.14 63RQjJaYK-rTFJ_qwOhBI0d-QH6TZ8_z_QtKX9fN0xXgm_pmKEf8oYa4ua18ByUtRBx1nB\r\n534-5.7.14 -GMpG-hb47bWHMSTq-i2SVX5P3YXhRD91F9zoNt1Rgzk7BrOX3bcZCz9DBP3ko> Please\r\n534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.\r\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\r\n534 5.7.14  [url]https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754[/url] a18sm444902ljf.35 - gsmtp\r\n\". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"534\", with message \"534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuI\r\n534-5.7.14 2A0XhMB-7K-5U3YxSA7QbcIwuvKjNc3dmwAMEUoAX1vpqtEuFTSrk6PLXVhZ0PIwW_QNQ2\r\n534-5.7.14 hkIF_7AIZzvoRKLUWdGW3UlqdkfPk0dSafE6LVM_glhq-DCTv_UJHxYjS17Kcb> Please\r\n534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.\r\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\r\n534 5.7.14  [url]https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754[/url] a18sm444902ljf.35 - gsmtp\r\n\". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code \"535\", with message \"535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\r\n535 5.7.8  [url]https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials[/url] a18sm444902ljf.35 - gsmtp\r\n\".",
        "exception": "Swift_TransportException",
        "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php",
        "line": 191,
        "trace": [
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php",
                "line": 371,
                "function": "afterEhlo",
                "class": "Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php",
                "line": 148,
                "function": "doHeloCommand",
                "class": "Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php",
                "line": 65,
                "function": "start",
                "class": "Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php",
                "line": 484,
                "function": "send",
                "class": "Swift_Mailer",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php",
                "line": 259,
                "function": "sendSwiftMessage",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php",
                "line": 159,
                "function": "send",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Localizable.php",
                "line": 19,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php",
                "line": 160,
                "function": "withLocale",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php",
                "line": 275,
                "function": "send",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php",
                "line": 229,
                "function": "sendMailable",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.php",
                "line": 127,
                "function": "send",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php",
                "line": 23,
                "function": "send",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "function": "order",
                "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\OrderController",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
                "line": 54,
                "function": "call_user_func_array"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
                "line": 45,
                "function": "callAction",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 219,
                "function": "dispatch",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 176,
                "function": "runController",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 680,
                "function": "run",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
                "line": 41,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
                "line": 75,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
                "line": 49,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
                "line": 56,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
                "line": 37,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
                "line": 66,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 104,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 682,
                "function": "then",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 657,
                "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 623,
                "function": "runRoute",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 612,
                "function": "dispatchToRoute",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 176,
                "function": "dispatch",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
                "line": 57,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
                "line": 27,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
                "line": 62,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 104,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 151,
                "function": "then",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 116,
                "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/home/s/shutruk/angel-abkhazia.ru/public/index.php",
                "line": 55,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is .env file settings (of mail):

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=narzantaria@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=narzantaria@gmail.com
    MAIL_FROM_NAME=Shutruk
```

mail.php settings:

```
    <?php

    return [

        'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

        'from' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'narzantaria@gmail.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
        ],

        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

        'markdown' => [
            'theme' => 'default',

            'paths' => [
                resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
            ],
        ],

        'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

    ];
```

It's really interest, what is the point, if at the local server it works, but when i copied it to the host without any changes, it became buggy.
I can no longer believe that this can be solved, great thanks to everyone for any help.
Execuse me my french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try checking , if you received a mail in your gmail account stating that you account is being used from some remote location. Gmail restricts the access to less secure app. You can enable in your smtp for less access app.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en